# Limit of $\vec{x} \rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|}$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to figure out what the authors of a (physics) paper mean by taking the
limit

$\lim\limits_{\vec{x} \rightarrow 0} \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|}$

Unfortunately there is no comment on this, but the goal is to have a numerical expression for this limit. Right now I'm not sure what this means mathematically.

Say $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$. Then I would say the result depends on which limit is taken first in each component. E.g. for $x_1$ we have

$\lim\limits_{x_1\rightarrow0} \lim\limits_{x_2\rightarrow0} \lim\limits_{x_3\rightarrow0} \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}$

Thus I would argue the answer is either $(1,0,0)$ or $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$.
Additionally by using spherical coordinates, the answer is $e_r$ (basis vector in $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ direction).

There seems to be an ambiguity here.

*Edit:

I keep this as simple as possible, but here is some additional information. This limit occurs when trying to remove a singularity in reciprocal space of the coulomb potential, i.e. we have $v \sim 1/q$, show that another quantity is $\sim \vec{q}$ and can then take the limit $\vec{q} \rightarrow 0$ without singularities.

Comment: Is $\overrightarrow x$ by any chance time-dependent, i.e. may "$\overrightarrow x\to0$" stand for "$t\to t_0$, where $\overrightarrow x(t_0)=0$" ?

Comment: No there is no time dependence involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows that this limit does not (in general) exist.

On the other hand, in physics it's pretty common to have hidden arguments to functions, so that $x$ really denotes $x(t)$, the position of a particle at time $t$, for instance. In such a case, it's possible that for some $t_0$, we have $\lim_{t \to t_0} x(t) = 0$, and perhaps the limit is nice (so that $x$ doesn't, for instance, take on the value $0$ anywhere near $t_0$ except *at* $t_0$); then writing 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}
$$
as a proxy for 
$$
\lim_{t \to t_0}
$$
may actually be reasonable, and may actually produce a meaningful value.

It also may not, as the example
$$
x(t) = (t^3 \sin \frac{1}{t}, t^3 \cos \frac{1}{t})
$$
for $t \ne 0$, $x(0) = (0,0)$, shows.

It's also possible that the paper's author is just sloppy or is writing nonsense, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example: take also $\;x_2=x_3=0\;$ , so that we *choose* to take the limit on the $\;x_1\,-$ axis:

$$\lim_{x_1\to0}\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2}}=\lim_{x_1\to0}\frac{x_1}{|x_1|}$$

and the last limits clearly doesn't exist as it different from the left and from the right side, and thus the limit you want doesn't exist.

Comment: You are of course correct. I realize that mathematical arguments probably won't bring me any further here.